# Add dependency dynamically in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, groovy, dependencies

Adobe Illustrator can create a bunch of files with different resolution and names them with `*dpi.png` and places in the same directory. Simultaneously, Android expect images to have the same name and be in different directories.

I wrote gradle script to do file copying and renaming:

```
[
    'ldpi', 'mdpi', 'hdpi', 'xhdpi', 'xxhdpi', 'xxxhdpi'
].each {
    String type = it

    task "copyAi_$it"(type: Copy) {



        String ending = '_Artboard 1' + type + '.png'

        from 'graphics_design/export/'

        include '*' + ending

        rename { String fileName ->
            fileName.replace( ending, '.png' )
        }

        into 'app/src/main/res/drawable-' + type
    }
}


task copyAiExport

copyAiExport.dependsOn copyAi_ldpi, copyAi_mdpi, copyAi_hdpi, copyAi_xhdpi, copyAi_xxhdpi, copyAi_xxxhdpi
```

As you see, I was to write all dependencies of overall task `copyAliExport` explicitly, enumerating all generated tasks.

Can I add dependencies dynamically too?

I found no understandable example in the doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it what are you looking for:

```
task all
[
    1, 2, 3, 4,
].each { n ->

    def t = task "task$n" {
      doLast {
        println n
      }
    }

    all.dependsOn << t
}
```

?

Comment: Don't know :) I can't read Groovy code easily yet. Probably this is it.

Comment: @Dims ;) Well, ok.  So you need to get a reference to just created task (`t`) and then get `all` dependencies (`dependsOn` == `getDependsOn`) and append `<<` task to it.

Comment: @Dims would you like me to rewrite your example?